# When i use the literal of the sequelize, there's no result

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

example:

```
attributes: [
db.sequelize.literal('COUNT(1)')
],
```

If i use it, a log is created.
(Executing (default): SELECT COUNT(1) as cnt FROM `TEST` AS `A`;

If this log was copied and used in the database, the desired results could be obtained normally.
(cnt : 20)

Did i miss the option about the literal ?

Answer (score 0):

do like this .

```
attributes: [
    [Sequelize.literal('COUNT(1)'),'Count']
],
```